Does this sentence have a double meaning?
Recently I asked a user on the web to upload a file somewhere, and it was returned with the answer: “I don’t even see the option to do that anymore.” Well, I understood it as a lack of desire for cooperation. And I replied: “So why did you ask me that question?”. To which I received the following: “I was looking to how to do it you f*** c***” and a spurt of other obscenities. Well, it really seems to be a communication failure. Surely, for not being a native speaker of English, I believe that my reaction contained a mocking tone for them. I would like to know if you guys can read that user’s first answer to me in two ways: 1) “I don’t know how to do it”, 2) “I don’t want to do it.”

Sadly, you're the one who misunderstood. It's not a lack of desire to help. It's how an English speaker would tell you there is no button to click on to upload the file. (The extra element is any more, which implies that maybe the software had that option in the past but "not any more".)

I agree with Peter.

OK, thanks. I really thought that “option” was about the situation where one could or could not upload the file. Like, “People have been asking me for this indefinite number of times, and I don’t consider this option anymore.” I can agree that I had a stupid moment, but, sure, there was no reason to fly off the handle like this. Too frustrated and too instable of him.

I don't really understand the question. It's obvious "the user" was initially trying to be cooperative, and I don’t even see the option to do that anymore clearly means I can't see how to [upload a file somewhere]. But I have no idea what the OP's text And I replied: “So why did you ask me that question?” means. The OP asked the user to do something [upload a file], but why would the OP have referred to the user asking the OP to do something? Given such a confusing question as presented here, it would hardly be surprising if "the user" lost patience with trying to help the OP!

Note, I don't know what industry this is or what role you and the other person have, but in most workplaces it's not okay to lose your temper, in even fewer is it okay to use profanity against someone else, and if the "c***" stands for an obscene sexist slur, that's okay in even even even fewer. In the US there are laws about "hostile work environments," and such an incident would often cause a big case with the human resources department. Perhaps there's more to the story, and a damaged working relationship before this story, and...

...  only the parts concerning language are within the scope of this site. But there are no extenuating circumstances that make that acceptable, and while I could imagine it being said jokingly among friends while working on the docks loading ships... it's not advisable or technically legal even there. Maybe workplace laws differ where you are. But I might not leave the incident unaddressed.

There’re no indications of (2).   In fact,
I was looking to how to do it ...
suggests that he wanted to do it, profanities notwithstanding. (These could be due to the frustration he faced trying to do the uploading.)
I don’t even see the option to do that anymore also doesn’t suggest (2).
This is more likely a case of the option being no longer available than the possibility that he didn’t know how to do it.  It could be both, though.

Understood. Thank you for the answer.
